# Array storage in python

Tags: python

I want to store a bunch of arrays for future use, how can I do this in python? I usually use 
append() method for element storage but this doesn't work with arrays.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're talking about either `list` or `array`, and both of those have `.append`...

Comment: "this doesn't work with arrays"?  Please provide (a) code and (b) error message.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using arrays? Do you mean lists? if your using lists then you can append lists (objects) anything to other lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about numpy arrays: either you append the elements to a list and construct an array from this list via `numpy.array(li)` or you use numpys `hstack()` resp. `vstack()`.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does provide an [`append`](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-12c005e9fff429abb657745defd2923dab55c62d) function.  The usage example given in the numpy documentation:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = array([10,20,30,40])
>>> append(a,50)
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
>>> append(a,[50,60])
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
>>> a = array([[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]])
>>> append(a,[[15,15,15]],axis=0)
array([[10, 20, 30],
       [40, 50, 60],
       [70, 80, 90],
       [15, 15, 15]])
>>> append(a,[[15],[15],[15]],axis=1)
array([[10, 20, 30, 15],
       [40, 50, 60, 15],
       [70, 80, 90, 15]])
```